# Call react route to Push Notification

Tags: reactjs, notifications

I want call a react route with php Symfony.

First I have create a function route in react like this:

```
import addNotification from 'react-push-notification';

const Notifications = () => {
    return (
        addNotification({
            title: 'Notification',
            subtitle: 'Welcome',
            message: 'New message',
            native: true
        })
    )
}

export default Notifications
```

This function display a notification when I call this route.

Second, When I try to access at this route, my notification work but I have
an error:

```
Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object
    Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an
    array instead.
```

I don't understand this error. Can you Help me about this ?

Third, Is-it possible to call this react route with symfony ?

Thanks

Comment: Please check docs for the correct usage of react-push-notification https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-push-notification#usage

Comment: @PavloZhukov I don't want use a button click. I need when I call the route a notification is display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't return objects from components.

If you want to launch a notification when this component is rendered, you need to do it in [useEffect hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html)

```
import React, {useEffect} from 'react'
import addNotification from 'react-push-notification';

const Notifications = () => {
    useEffect(() => {
        addNotification({
            title: 'Notification',
            subtitle: 'Welcome',
            message: 'New message',
            native: true
        })
    }, [])
    return null
}

export default Notifications
```